# How to fix duplicate MAC Addresses on Ethernet?

Tags: macos, ethernet, mac-address, chromebook

For some reason, whenever I connect to ethernet on my Chromebook and my Macbook, the MAC Address is the exact same. As expected, this renders the ethernet unusable for both computers, but at least neither have the MAC Address on the wifi. The ethernet is connected to a "satellite" (don't know if it is actually called this but that's what it was called in the packaging) and directly connects to a docking station that I use with both laptops. This problem seemed to arise a few weeks ago, but it was working fine before that. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "docking station that I use with both laptops"? What are you doing exactly?

Comment: I plug a cable into the computer I want to use and plug all the equipment I am using into the adapter, so I don't have to plug a lot of wires into my laptop.

Comment: How can you use it with both laptops, or do you use the dock with one computer at a time?

Comment: One computer at a time, the writing is a bit confusing.

Comment: If only one computer is connected at a time, how can a duplicate MAC address cause a problem? And for both computers too? The MAC might even come from the dock, not the computers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the MAC address of one of the machines. I suggest the Chromebook.

It is not often that MAC addresses are duplicates, so be careful with your change.

Here is the method:

[https://www.techjunkie.com/change-mac-address-chromebook/#:~:text=Hold%20down%20the%20Ctrl%20%2B%20Alt,sudo%20ifconfig%20wlan0%20down](https://www.techjunkie.com/change-mac-address-chromebook/#:%7E:text=Hold%20down%20the%20Ctrl%20%2B%20Alt,sudo%20ifconfig%20wlan0%20down)

> To change the Mac address on your Chromebook, you’ll have to be in
> developer mode.  Be aware that this also makes your Chromebook
> slightly less protected when doing so, as there is a layer of security
> that gets taken away. It will also wipe out anything on your
> Chromebook, so make sure you’ve backed everything up beforehand.
>
> After you’ve logged into your Chromebook device in developer mode, you
> then need to get into the developer Crosh or Command Shell.  You’re
> going to do that from the Chrome browser.  Hold down the Ctrl + Alt +
> T keys on your keyboard.  This opens the command line in the Chrome
> browser.
>
> Now you can briefly change your Mac address on your Chromebook device
> by typing the following commands for a Wi-Fi connection;
>
> sudo ifconfig wlan0 down sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether
> 00:11:22:33:44:55 (or whatever you like as your fake Mac address) sudo
> ifconfig wlan0 up These commands shut down your internet connect for
> you to change your Mac address and then bring it back up once
> completed.
>
> The commands for an Ethernet connected Chromebook device are;
>
> sudo ifconfig eth0 down sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
> (or whatever you like as your fake Mac address) sudo ifconfig eth0 up
>
> Okay, so now you should have been able to change the Mac address
> temporarily on your Chromebook, being in developer mode.  When you
> reboot your Chromebook device, the Mac address goes back to the
> original Mac address because it’s assigned to the network device.
>
> Anytime you want to change your Mac address on your Chromebook, you’ll
> need to go through the steps above whenever you reboot your Chromebook
> and need to spoof your actual Mac address.

If you need to change the MAC address on the Macbook for any reason, follow this tutorial

[https://beebom.com/how-change-mac-address-mac/#:~:text=Change%20MAC%20Address%20in%20macOS,the%20%E2%80%9Cinterface%20name%E2%80%9D%20there](https://beebom.com/how-change-mac-address-mac/#:%7E:text=Change%20MAC%20Address%20in%20macOS,the%20%E2%80%9Cinterface%20name%E2%80%9D%20there).

*Also consider returning the Chromebook to the school for a different machine, if the school will do this for you.*

Comment: The problem with the Chromebook is that it is one lent to me by my school so I cannot change the MAC Address on it as they have restricted use of developer mode. Is there a way to change the MAC Address on the Macbook?

Comment: I added a Macbook tutorial. Again use care changing the MAC address.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll try this as soon as I can!